# PHP Xpath: Get all href's that contain "letter"

Tags: php, xpath, html-parsing

Say I have an html file that I have loaded, I run this query:

```
$url = 'http://www.fangraphs.com/players.aspx';
$html = file_get_contents($url);    
$myDom = new DOMDocument;
$myDom->formatOutput = true;
@$myDom->loadHTML($html);
$anchor = $xpath->query('//a[contains(@href,"letter")]');
```

That gives me a list of these anchors that look like the following:

```
<a href="players.aspx?letter=Aa">Aa</a>
```

But I need a way to only get "players.aspx?letter=Aa".

I thought I could try:

```
$anchor = $xpath->query('//a[contains(@href,"letter")]/@href');
```

But that gives me a php error saying I couldn't append node when I try the following:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($myDom);
$newDom = new DOMDocument;
$j = 0;
while( $myAnchor = $anchor->item($j++) ){
   $node = $newDom->importNode( $myAnchor, true );    // import node
   $newDom->appendChild($node);
}
```

Any idea how to obtain just the value of the href tags that the first query selects?? Thanks!

Comment: This works without any error for me .. can I see more of the code, e.g. the xml that is the DOM for newDom?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I wasn't clear. It wasn't XML, it's an HTML file loaded in. Could you take a look at the original post again? I have edited the top portion of it to reflect how I am obtaining the DOM.

Comment: Still not enough -- you are missing where `xpath` and `newDom` get initialized

Comment: Sorry, they were just being initialized so I left them out. I have added them into the last code segment. (at the top). Take a look again? Sorry for the trouble

Comment: Did you manage to take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPath query is returning attributes themselves (i.e., `DOMAttr` objects) rather than elements (i.e., `DOMElement` objects). That's fine, and that seems to be what you want, but appending them to the document is the problem. A `DOMAttr` is not a standalone node in the document tree; it's associated with a `DOMElement` but is not a *child* in the usual sense. Thus, directly appending a `DOMAttr` to the document is invalid.

From [the W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-DOM-Level-3-Core-20030226/DOM3-Core.html#core-ID-637646024):

> `Attr` objects inherit the `Node` interface, but since they are not actually child nodes of the element they describe, the DOM does not consider them part of the document tree. . . . The DOM takes the view that attributes are properties of elements rather than having a separate identity from the elements they are associated with

Either associate the `DOMAttr` with a `DOMElement` and append that element, or pull out the `DOMAttr`'s value and use that as you wish.

To just append its plain text value, use its value in a `DOMText` node and append that. For example, change this line:

```
    $newDom->appendChild($node);
```

to this:

```
    $newDom->appendChild(new DOMText($node->value));
```

Answer (score 3):

**Use**:

```
//a/@href[contains(., 'letter')]
```

**this selects any `href` attribute of any `a` whose string value (of the attribute) contains the string `"letter"`** .

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$xml_string = 'your xml string';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
foreach($xml->a[0]->attributes() as $href => $value) {
    $myAnchorsValues[] = $value;
}

var_dump($myAnchorsValues);
```

Comment: Actually it's not xml...it's an HTML file loaded into a DOMDocument. Could you take another look at the original post again? I edited the top part to include where I'm getting the content from.

Comment: you may try with this parser: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ worked for me.
if you need an example let me know, but its very clearer in the documentation.